# Can I collect the 'Hard Only' lollipop wrappers in ranked mode?

Tags: lollipop-chainsaw

I'm working towards getting the Platinum trophy in Lollipop Chainsaw,  the requirements include registering a score for every level in Ranked Mode and collecting all lollipop wrappers.

I've completed the game on Easy difficulty, and some of the lollipop wrappers aren't available unless you're playing on Hard, can I play the ranked levels on that difficulty and still collect those wrappers or do I need to replay each level on Hard and non-ranked? Does it matter which ranked mode type I choose? (Score/Medal/Time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you play ranked mode on hard difficulty, the "Hard-only" wrappers will appear in the levels and can be collected.